# Normal map comes out wrong from baking

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, normals, normal-map

I am making a train in blender and I want to use normal maps to show panelling and rivets without having to add it to the model. To try this I have made a model with some rivets as shown below (first picture) which I want to bake onto the low detail model (second picture)[image: Train with Rivets]

[image: Train without rivets]

However when I try to bake it to a normal map, regardless of what ray distance I use, the normal map comes out looking distorted and green as you can see here:

[image]

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I am very stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to increase the Extrusion value?

Comment: @Jummit I tried that but when I set the value below 20 the map is still distorted albeit there is less distortion. When I set it above 20 the map is completely blank.

Comment: Try setting it to .2 or even less.

Comment: Still no luck, I am going to try drawing the normal map instead, thanks for the help